# How to put Saris Bones 3 rack on Honda Odyssey 2001?

Tags: road-bike, car-rack

I want to buy a [Saris Bones 3 strap-on bike rack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BT30RU) for my Honda Odyssey EX 2001. However, the [fit guide](http://www.saris.com/en/vehicle-racks.html) on the Saris website does not list 2001 model. I called their customer service and was told that it could fit my car but I might have to change the upper hook straps. However, they couldn't tell me where to find the different ones.

Does the Saris Bones 3 rack fit Odyssey 2001? If not, what am I likely to have to do to get the rack to fit a different car to what it's designed for?

Comment: whoever vote this question down wants to explain the reason why?

Comment: It is very, very specific. Too specific to be widely useful. It would be better to say "how could I fit a strap-on rack to my hatchback if it doesn't quite fit?" (not that I downvoted your question, but that's why I've edited it)

Comment: Indeed, with a little bit of editing to make it less specific, this could be a great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like any hatchback. I have a toyota matrix and here is how I do it:

1. Adjust the inner legs so they sit on the "step" of the bumper.
2. Adjust the outer legs so they rest against the back window - this makes them almost parallel.
3. Place all straps in the appropriate locations
4. Tighten down lower straps
5. Tighten upper straps
6. Tighten side straps
7. Repeat all tightening.
8. done.

The only issue I see might be the fairing on the top of your window. A lot of trunk mount racks are hindered by this because you can't really tighten down the straps enough to properly secure the rack. if you can go UNDER the fairing and attach to the edge, that would be advisable.

A hitch mount rack might be better suited for your vehicle.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found there's also a Hatch Hanger that needed to be use with this rack for some certain model of car including my car model.